# Cannot set window text with Unicode special char

Tags: c++, c, unicode, mfc

I'm trying to set dialog item text by code with the unicode special character specified below:

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f310/index.htm

I have been trying calling SetWindowTextW function passing UTF-16(hex) value as parameter without success:

```
GetDlgItem(IDSETTINGS)->SetWindowTextW(_T("\uD83C\uDF10"));
```

When I build my solution I got two errors:

*error C3850: '\uD83C' a universal-character-.name specifies an invalid character*

*error C3850: '\uDF10' a universal-character-.name specifies an invalid character*

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Have you tried `""`?

Comment: `SetWindowTextW` and `_T()` are incompatible. Use `L""` with the Unicode version of API calls.

Comment: You can usually get a more in-depth explanation by looking up the error codes in the MSDN.

Comment: Is there any way to increase the size of the icon?, I have trying using SetFont() function but it doesn't works.... thank for your help

Comment: it's a text character, not an image icon. But the interface font settings AFAIK are  applied for the whole system, not for a single window

Comment: You can set the font individually for each window.

Comment: `L"\xD83C\xDF10"` will work also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case the reason for compiler error C3850 can be found in the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3850) (emphasis mine):

> Characters represented as universal character names must represent
>   valid Unicode code points in the range 0-10FFFF. A universal character
>   name **cannot contain a value in the Unicode surrogate range, D800-DFFF**,
>   or an encoded surrogate pair. The compiler generates the surrogate
>   pair from a valid code point automatically.

Using the UTF-32 code point works for me:

```
GetDlgItem( IDSETTINGS )->SetWindowTextW( L"\U0001F310" );
```

You can also literally store the character in the source file if you make sure the source file is stored with a Unicode encoding, I suggest to use UTF-8 with BOM.

```
GetDlgItem( IDSETTINGS )->SetWindowTextW( L"" );
```

Note that you should never use the `_T()` nor `_TEXT()` macros when using a `W` (Unicode) API. These macros change the type of string literal depending on preprocessor variables, whereas the Unicode APIs always expect wide strings, which is enforced by using the `L` prefix for the string literal.

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Worth noting, that error [C3850](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3850) is raised, because the code in question tries to encode a surrogate pair. *"A universal character name cannot contain a value in the Unicode surrogate range, D800-DFFF, or an encoded surrogate pair. The compiler generates the surrogate pair from a valid code point automatically."*

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I've added relevant citation from the reference.